# Configure MailDev to relay mails to an external server

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker

I have to use MailDev with Docker. And I use the djfarrelly/maildev image on Docker Hub.
Until now I always started it like that:

```
 docker run --name srvm-smtp -p 1080:80 -p 1025:25 djfarrelly/maildev bin/maildev
 --web 80\
 --smtp 25
```

But now I need to send mails to an external server(gmail on sample). I find on the web options for that:

```
$ maildev --outgoing-host smtp.gmail.com \
          --outgoing-secure \
          --outgoing-user 'you@gmail.com' \
          --outgoing-pass '<pass>'
```

Where and how I can use it in my situation where I use docker image?

PS. I was try add they to the run docker command like options, but it doesn't work. Like this:

```
docker run --name srvm-smtp -p 1080:80 
-p 1025:25 djfarrelly/maildev bin/maildev
 --web 80
 --smtp 25
 --outgoing-host smtp.gmail.com
  --outgoing-secure 
  --outgoing-user 'you@gmail.com'
  --outgoing-pass '<pass>'
```

But I got error " --outgoung-host: command not found...... "
And same for any option..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing a command in multiline. Which needs special handling. Either execute the whole thing in one line

```
docker run --name srvm-smtp -p 1080:80 -p 1025:25 djfarrelly/maildev bin/maildev --web 80 --smtp 25 --outgoing-host smtp.gmail.com  --outgoing-secure   --outgoing-user 'you@gmail.com'  --outgoing-pass '<pass>'
```

or else add `\` at the end of each line for continuation

```
docker run --name srvm-smtp -p 1080:80 \
-p 1025:25 djfarrelly/maildev bin/maildev \
 --web 80 \
 --smtp 25 \
 --outgoing-host smtp.gmail.com \
  --outgoing-secure \
  --outgoing-user 'you@gmail.com' \
  --outgoing-pass '<pass>'
```

Comment: I did do that, but still it didn't work. I know for that. Only if I have miss one line for continuation?
But you want to say that is correct way, to add option?